# FJTask vs Future+Callables+ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Objective: to make something like unpretentious map/reduce.
There are many tasks they should be run in parallel, results added to the collection. If the task lasts longer than a certain time (eg 3 seconds) - cancel it.
Which way is faster and more convenient? Share your experiences in building a "correct" multi-threading.
thx in advance.

**FJTask**
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [ParallelArrayWithMapping](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/extra166ydocs/extra166y/ParallelArrayWithMapping.html).  It is used in a ForkJoinPool (similar useage with FJTask).  There is a method called reduce that may help you.  Using a Fork Join Pool and the java 7 FJ Framework is very fast and offers nice exploitations of all available processors.